# combine two plots in R . second plot is repalcing the first one

Tags: r

```
#qcc package(spc charts)
library(qcc)
A <- c(10,20,30)
B <- c(25,35,44)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
qcc(A,type="xbar.one")
qcc(B,type="xbar.one")
```

problem is : chart(B) is replacing chart(A) instead of positiong in the second row.
someone please let me know how to overcome these problem

Comment: sorry for the edit....

Comment: i am facing the problem when i plot spc charts, not the normal graphs

Comment: That is why a reproducible example is necessary from the beginning. It avoids waste of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There probably is a kind of bug and also, you need to use `plot`.

Here is a solution to make it work :

```
qA<-qcc(A,type="xbar.one")
qB<-qcc(B,type="xbar.one")  

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(qA, restore.par=FALSE)
plot(qB)
```

*The strange (probably bug?) part is that doing the below thing doesn't work... :*

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(qcc(A,type="xbar.one"),restore.par=FALSE)
plot(qcc(B,type="xbar.one"))
```

Comment: Wow - what a thing... Nice post, @Cath. I was attempting a 3x2 plot with xbar/S combos. I had to add restore.par=FALSE to all 6 plots and it finally worked.